# Capture all commands output

Tags: winapi, freepascal, output-redirect

I want to capture cmd.exe output and show it in a diffrent gui I am making. I want to make a command interpreter with extended functionality. The dir command works flawless, the problem ocurrs when I try to execute another process like ipconfig.

I don't see ipconfig output. Is there a workarround on that ?!

I use TProcess component from Lazarus (FreePascal)

```
  proc := TProcess.Create(nil);
  proc.Options:= [poUsePipes, poNoConsole];
  proc.ShowWindow:= swoHIDE;
  proc.Executable:= 'cmd';
```

Reading output thread:

```
  if (Length(cmd) > 0) then
         begin
         cmd := cmd + #13#10;
         proc.Input.Write(cmd[1], Length(cmd)); // here I write command from user
         strikes := 0;
         end
      else
      if proc.Output.NumBytesAvailable > 0 then
      begin
           while proc.Output.NumBytesAvailable > 0 do
           begin
                FillChar(buf, sizeof(buf), #0);
                proc.Output.Read(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
                data := data + buf;
           end;                    

         // data gets echoed to user
```

Comment: We cannot see your code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I use TProcess from lazarus suite, this are the creation flags. Don't think the code is wrong

Comment: `proc.ShowWindow` serves no purpose. It's a console app, `poNoConsole` is what matters. If you showed a complete program that would help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I posted the part that does the reading and writing to cmd process. As I said it works with all commands that execute internal in cmd.exe but not that spawn in new process

Comment: Seems kind of odd to me. If I were to investigate further I think I'd want to do some debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me (I use FPC 3.1.1 & Lazarus 1.5 but I hope it does not matter):

```
proc.Options:= [poUsePipes];
proc.ShowWindow:= swoHIDE;
proc.Executable:= 'cmd'; 
...

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
    cmd: String;
begin
    if Key = #13 then
    begin
        Key := #0;
        if not proc.Active then
            proc.Active := True;
        cmd := Edit1.Text + LineEnding;
        proc.Input.Write(cmd[1], Length(cmd));
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
    buf: array[0..65535] of Char;
begin
    if proc.Output.NumBytesAvailable > 0 then
    begin
        while proc.Output.NumBytesAvailable > 0 do
        begin
            FillChar(buf, sizeof(buf), #0);
            proc.Output.Read(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
            Memo1.Lines.Add(buf);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

I guess that you just does not catch process output properly.
Good luck.

PS: If you need to create some windows console-like application, the best way, I think, is using [Windows console API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682087.aspx) instead of cross-platform Lazarus components.

PPS: To emulate console look and behavior with Lazarus use [CmdLine](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/CmdLine) component.

Comment: removed poNoConsole from component creation routine and it works! Thanks for help bro

Answer (score 1):

In general it is smart to first check if the short examples don't solve the problem:

e.g.

```
uses process;

var s : ansistring;
begin
  runcommand('ipconfig',['/all'],s);
  writeln(s);
end.
```

works fine, and saves a whole lot of trouble. (FPC 2.6.2+ though)